# java array for zigzag works, but tester keeps telling me there's an error?

Tags: java, arrays

I have this line of code to create a zigzag array, its fairly simple and I already have the code for it. here's the summary of the question:

This method creates and returns a new two-dimensional integer array, which in Java is really just a one-dimensional array whose elements are one-dimensional arrays of type int[]. The returned array must have the correct number of rows that each have exactly cols columns. This array must contain the numbers start, start + 1, ..., start + (rows * cols - 1) in its rows in order, except that the elements in each odd-numbered row must be listed in descending order.

For example, when called with rows = 4, cols = 5 and start = 4, this method should create and return the two-dimensional array whose contents are

```
4   5   6   7   8
13  12  11  10  9
14  15  16  17  18
23  22  21  20  19
```

I've tried talking with my colleagues but they can't spot the problem too

```
public class P2J1
{
public static int[][] createZigZag(final int rows, final int cols, int start)
    {
        final int[][] array = new int[rows][cols];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                array[i][j] = start;
                start++;
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
}
/// heres the tester program

@Test public void testCreateZigZag() {
        Random rng = new Random(SEED);
        CRC32 check = new CRC32();
        for(int i = 0; i < TRIALS; i++) {
            int rows = rng.nextInt(20) + 1;
            int cols = rng.nextInt(20) + 1;
            int start = rng.nextInt(100);
            int[][] zig = P2J1.createZigZag(rows, cols, start);
            assertEquals(rows, zig.length);
            for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
                assertEquals(cols, zig[j].length);
                for(int e: zig[j]) { check.update(e); }
            }
        }
        assertEquals(3465650385L, check.getValue());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your column index always goes from 0 to cols-1, in that order.  You need to alternate the order every other row.

You can do this by using variables for the start, end, and increment of the inner loop and assign those variables based on the row index being odd or even.

Something like this (untested):

```
public static int[][] createZigZag(final int rows, final int cols, int start) {
    final int[][] array = new int[rows][cols];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        boolean backwards = ((i & 1) == 1);
        final int jStart = backwards ? cols-1 :   -1;
        final int jEnd   = backwards ?      0 : cols;
        final int jStep  = backwards ?     -1 :    1;

        for (int j = jStart; j != jEnd; j += jStep) {
            array[i][j] = start;
            start++;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

You could also just write two different inner loops, selected on the same condition.  One would fill starting from 0, the other would fill starting from cols-1 and going backwards.

```
public static int[][] createZigZag(final int rows, final int cols, int start) {
    final int[][] array = new int[rows][cols];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        if ((i & 1) == 1) {
            for (int j = cols-1; j >= 0; j--) {
                array[i][j] = start;
                start++;
            }
        } else {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                array[i][j] = start;
                start++;
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: how would I assign those variables, for every other row?  I'm sorry it's just that I'm still struggling with arrays on java.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a modified inner loop that works in the manner I described.

Comment: yes but the line ``` (i & 1 == 1)``` comes oout as a bad operand types for binaty operantor '&'  first type: int second type: boolean

Comment: I apologize for doing this quickly and not in an IDE that would have hinted at my error.  Fixed the order of operations.  Though the error message was clear, you should study it and understand it before moving on.  If you don't get a good understanding of these basics, you are going to make things a lot harder than they need to be.